# start more than one process at the same time with bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit # Exit on error

# Enable script to run from anywhere
cd "$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"

root=$(pwd)

cd "../../../"
source ./somebashscript

cd "../../../..."

source ./otherbashscript
```

both source commands will launch their own process.

How do I launch both processes from the same bash script?

Comment: Using `&` will start both scripts in the background and allow you to do it from the same script

Comment: It makes no sense to put `source` in the background. The purpose of `source` is to execute the code **in the current shell**. If you don't need to do that, don't use `source`, just do `./somebashscript &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `&` at the end of the command starts the process in the background.

```
cd "../../../"
source ./somebashscript &

cd "../../../..."

source ./otherbashscript &
```

You may want to redirect the output of the scripts to somewhere else, otherwise everything will be printed to your screen. You can do that by adding `> file.log` if you want to log the output, or `> /dev/null` if you want to drop it

```
source ./somebashscript > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Brilliant, how do I stop both processes?

Comment: You have two options; capturing the PID of each process or using `pkill <process name>` to kill the process by name

Comment: @dagda1 if you have found my answer useful, please kindly consider upvoting and accepting it. thanks